Drag image in label to place or draw another label pyqt5
I want to do this on PyQt5. I placed an image inside the label area using Pixmap, and there is also an image on label-2. Here's what I want to do: I want to drag the image on the label (keeping the original in place, i.e., cloning it) and clone it onto the image on label-2 at a position I specify. While doing this, I want to position it on the other widget by dragging and dropping. I've written an algorithm for the dragging operation, but I can't draw it on the label. How can I achieve this?
I want drag label-1 drop to label-2. . I want to be able to move it more than once, so label-1 will always remain (collapsed) and label-2 can be moved on it.

What I want:

This is my code:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from test import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint





class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.boxes = []  # Klonlanmış box'ların listesi

        self.original_box = QPixmap("box.png").scaled(100, 150)  # Orjinal box resmi
        self.original_palette = QPixmap("palette.png")
        # print( self.img.width(),self.img.height())
        self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.original_box)
        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

        self.dragging = False  # Sürükleme durumu
        self.offset = None  # Sürükleme konumu
        self.ui.image.setFixedSize(self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
        self.ui.palet.setFixedSize(self.original_palette.width(), self.original_palette.height())
        # self.ui.image.setScaledContents(True)
        self.ui.image.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ui.image.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")

        self.ui.palet.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ui.palet.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")
        print("After")
        self.ui.widget_2.setAcceptDrops(True)  # Bırakma işlemini kabul et

        self.rectangle = QRect(500,400,self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())



    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 10)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRect(self.rectangle)
        painter.drawEllipse(285, 45, 30, 50)
        # self.update()

        # Orjinal box'ı çiz
        # painter.drawPixmap(100, 150, self.original_box)

        # print("draw",self.dragging)

        # Sürüklenen box'ı çiz
        if self.dragging:
            # print(self.dragging)

            painter.drawPixmap(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2,
                               self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2,
                               self.original_box)
            # self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.original_box)



        # Klonlanmış box'ları çiz
        for box in self.boxes:
            painter.drawPixmap(box.topLeft(), self.original_box)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # print("MAUSE GLOBAL POS",self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))
            # print(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())))
            print(self.ui.widget_2.rect())
            if(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))):
                self.dragging = True
                self.offset = event.pos()
                print("Offset point", self.offset)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging:
            # print("DRAGGING")
            # Sürüklenen box'ın merkezini güncelle
            self.offset = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.dragging:
            print("RELEASE")
            self.dragging = False
            # Yeni box'ı oluştur
            new_box = QRect(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2,
                            self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2,
                            self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
            self.boxes.append(new_box)
            self.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


It isn't really clear what you are asking... you want to copy the image in 1 label to another label in a different widget and position it according to where you droped it?  Is that what you want to do?

I want drag label-1 drop to label-2 .I don't understand why it seems incomprehensible. I want to be able to move it more than once, so label-1 will always remain (collapsed) and label-2 can be moved on it.

@Alexander I also add the image what I want

I still don't understand
